# Configuring database access for local version of Heroku app

Tags: java, postgresql, heroku

I'm modifying the "Getting Started on Heroku with Java" sample app ([documentation from Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java) / [source on Github](https://github.com/heroku/java-getting-started/)) and having trouble with my **local** database connection.

The relevant code is from the main class:

```
public class Main {
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String dbUrl;

[...]

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        if (dbUrl == null || dbUrl.isEmpty()) {
            return new HikariDataSource();
        } else {
            HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
            config.setJdbcUrl(dbUrl);
            return new HikariDataSource(config);
        }
    }
```

The value of `dbUrl` is pulled by Spring from the `application.properties` file, which has the contents

```
spring.datasource.url: ${JDBC_DATABASE_URL:}
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10

[...]
```

So, the properties file just refers to another variable, `${JDBC_DATABASE_URL:}`. According to [Heroku's documentation on database connections](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java), `${JDBC_DATABASE_URL:}` is generated at runtime. On the deployed version, the app figures out the "real" DB URL just fine, but when I [run locally](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local), I get the Hikari error

> dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.

when attempting to access the DB or even just get a connection from the connection pool.

I've already

- downloaded the latest version of Postgres to my local machine
- verified that it's using port 5432 as expected
- set the DATABASE_URL environment variable on the command line using `set DATABASE_URL=postgres://my_db_user:somePassword@localhost:5432/my_local_db_name`

What more configuration do I have to do to get the app to run locally? Or more specifically, how do I get the local version of the app to have the correct `DATABASE_URL/JDBC_DATABASE_URL` value?

Comment: What is your Operating System?

Comment: @clarity123 Win10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting `DATABASE_URL` locally, set `JDBC_DATABASE_URL` like this:

```
JDBC_DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_local_db_name?user=my_db_user&password=somePassword
```

You can also put this in your `.env` file if you're using `heroku local`.

Comment: Won't hard-coding that prevent the application from picking up the correct value when it's deployed to production, though?

Comment: No, according to documentation `The .env file lets you capture all the config vars that you need in order to run your app locally. ` The way they describe it sounds like it is purpose built for local use. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local . Even on the github you linked it says `ensure you have a local .env file` so even here it is treated as a local matter. https://github.com/heroku/java-getting-started/

Comment: `.env` is not used remotely (on heroku) and should even be added to your `.gitignore`.

Comment: `.env ... should only be used for local configuration. Update your .gitignore file to exclude the .env file.` https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#copy-heroku-config-vars-to-your-local-env-file

Comment: Ah... I read that note but misinterpreted it. I guess it doesn't matter how anymore. This does work. I guess my earlier attempts to change the value in the system were having no effect because the default `.env` file had a value for `DATABASE_URL` that was overriding them? In any case, please enjoy a well-deserved checkmark. I'll try to remember to come back and upvote when I've earned that priv.

Comment: @codefinger gets credit for thinking about `.env` first. If you like my documentation mention you can just upvote the particular comment, thanks :)

Comment: @clarity123 I don't think so... looks like comment voting is a package deal with "comment everywhere"-ing. Thank you, though!